# Error with cleveref + enumerate + tikz-qtree

Tags: tikz-pgf, lists, cleveref, tikz-trees

I get an error in my document in the following circumstance:

1. Using the `cleveref` package
2. And the `tikz-qtree` package (for drawing syntax trees)
3. Inside an `enumerate` environment

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{cleveref} %Uncomment for crash

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item foo
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \Tree [.Foo Bar ]
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

Here's a link to the log that running that file (with `cleveref` uncommented) generates: [log file](http://www.ling.upenn.edu/~ecay/test_tikz.log).  The first error is:

```
! Package tikz Error: A node must have a (possibly empty) label text.
```

I've verified the following things:

- It is not a catcode problem, i.e. the
  catcode of `.` and `[` is 12 both with
  and without loading `cleveref`
- The problem goes away if the tree is
  not embedded in an enumerate, i.e.
  delete the entire document body and
  replace it with only the
  `\begin{tikzpicture}...\end{tikzpicture}`
- The problem goes away if you change
  the `enumerate` to `itemize`

I tried running the example with `\traceon` from the `trace` package, but got mired in the half-million(!) lines of output.

Based on the esoteric combination of packages, I'm not sure a ready answer exists, but hopefully there is a TeX guru out there familiar with the guts of these packages who sees something I cannot.

Comment: It also fails with the `gb4e` and `linguex` examples.  So this is something quite general with lists.

Comment: This question has been upvoted enough times that it looks like it deserves an answer, so I've offered a bounty on it. Most upvoted answer this time next week gets it.

Comment: @Seamus Thanks for adding the bounty to this question -- it looks like it was just what was needed to smoke out the answer.  As far as I understand, if I accept Ulrich's answer, he will get the bounty.  You mentioned waiting a week, but consensus seems to be that his answer is deserving.  Any objections if I go ahead and accept it?

Comment: I'm not sure whether accepting the answer will trigger the bounty, since it wasn't offered by the asker. But I'm perfectly happy for Ulrich to get the bounty so go ahead and accept!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My money is on a name clash of `\@result`. There's a suspicious

```
\@call #1#2->\let \@cont =#2\bgroup \@result ={}#1
#1<-\@subtree 
#2<-\@Tree 
{\let}
{begin-group character {}

\@result ->
{the character =}
Missing character: There is no = in font nullfont!
{begin-group character {}
{end-group character }}
```

in the log. Without having checked right now, I conjecture that TikZ has a token register of that name, while cleveref uses it as a macro.

Comment: `\@result` is  the problem but not in TikZ but in tikz-qtree and in cleveref

Comment: Sadly, `grep -rl '\\@result'` reveals nothing in the PGF directories (and all the results of `grep -r @result` are normal so there's no apparent `\csname` trickery).  Though not knowing much of the mysteries of TeX, could it be encoded in some weird way?

Comment: Ah, yes.  As Altermundus says, line 30 of `tikz-qtree.sty` reads `\newtoks\@result`.  That should be easy to patch.  I guess that _both_ packages should choose better names!

Comment: Ulrich should get the bounty.  I'm annoyed that I missed this when I looked into this last week! Changing all instances of `\@result` to `\tkqt@result` fixes the problem.  I'm in contact with the author of tikz-qtree, so I'll send a fix along to him.

Comment: I've notified the authors of both packages.

Comment: @Ulrich could you edit your answer to reflect the comments discussion?

Comment: For the record, this and all other name clashes should be fixed since at least version 0.18 of `cleveref`. (All temporary internal cleveref macros use a `cref@` prefix for safety's sake.)

Answer (score 9):

A solution :

in  tikz-qtree.tex you can replace `\@result` by `\qt@result`