# Best practice for fixing a clash between packages without altering the .sty files?

Tags: packages, best-practices, incompatibility

Here is another casualty of TeX's flat namespace and another reason to start using LaTeX3...

I noticed today that the `algorithm2e` and `keystroke` packages clash. More specifically, they both define a command called `\Return`:

- in `algorithm2e`, `\Return` is a command for typesetting the pseudocode *Return* keyword;
- in `keystroke`, `\Return` is a command that typesets <kbd>Return</kbd>.

Both packages define their `\Return` command using `\newcommand`; therefore, if both packages are loaded, LaTeX returns an error when it encounters the second `\newcommand\Return`.

I solved the problem by giving `keystroke`'s `\Return` a new, unique name that doesn't clash with anything I'm using so far, like so:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{keystroke}
\let\ksReturn\Return
\let\Return\relax
\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}
\Return \quad \ksReturn
\end{document}
```

That worked, but I have a question:

As a user (not a package writer/maintainer), what is best practice for fixing a clash between two homonymous, yet different, commands defined in two different packages, without altering either of the .sty files?
Can my approach have any detrimental side-effect (aside from my new name possibly generating a different clash)?

---

Side note: `keystroke` is quite an old package. At the time of writing this post, the current version dates back to November 2000, whereas the current version of `algorithm2e` was released more recently, in January 2013.

**Edit**: a less problematic and more powerful package for typesetting menu sequences,
paths, and keyboard shortcuts is the excellent [`menukeys` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/menukeys).

Comment: If the command you redefine is used internally in the package, that could obviously have some bad side-effects.  Something to think about.

Comment: @SeanAllred That's a good point! In this specific case, I actually checked beforehand: `\Return` occurs only once in `keystroke.sty`: in its own definition. Therefore, no problem here; but otherwise, my approach would be problematic, you're right. One would hope that the package writer would use `@` in her internal-command names to reduce the risk of conflict, but not everyone follows that practice.

Comment: In an ideal world, the macros to be used only inside an environment such as `algorithm` would be defined just there and not at the outer level. But even this wouldn't solve all problems, because it's not so strange thinking to use the `\Return` key symbol inside `algorithm`. Probably the `keystroke` package should have defined its commands in the form `\key{Return}`. Oh, no! `\key` is used somewhere else…

Comment: @egreg The `keystroke` package does have a `\keystroke` (not `\key`) macro for typesetting keyboard keys.

Answer (score 2):

First, save the clashing identifiers:

```
\usepackage{keystroke}
\let\keystroke@Return\Return
\let\Return\undefined
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\let\algorithmtwoe@Return\Return
\let\Return\undefined
```

Then defined two macros to setup the correct bindings.

```
\def\keystroke@setupbindings{%
   \let\Return\keystroke@Return
}
\def\algorithmtwoe@setupbindings{%
   \let\Return\algorithmtwoe@Return
}
```

Last patch the entry points using `\Return` so that they start with the appropriate `@setupbindings` macro. You can do this programatically by loading the replacement text of that entry point in a token register and refefining the entrypoint with `\edef`:

```
% Some code that loads the expansion text of \entrypoint in toks0
\edef\entrypoint{\noexpand\keystroke@setupbindings\the\toks0}
```

It is impossible to attain the largest level of genericity because, to the best of my knowledge, it is not possible to recover the application template of a macro in TeX. But if you really need this, you can write `\patch` macro so that

```
\patch\entrypoint\keystroke@setupbindings
```

does the same thing as the pseudo-code above. Dealing with `\long` and `\outer` modificators and macros having arguments can be a bit tedious, though, so it might be suitable to semi-manually patch the relevant macros.

EDIT — Well, it is actually possible to recover the application template of a macro and I should know this pretty good since I included a macro doing this in my *Bhrìd TeX* format! :-)  Here is an untested translation for plain TeX:

```
\begingroup
  \edef\next{%
  \gdef\noexpand\toksloadmeaning@A
  ##1\noexpand\and##2\expandafter
  \ignore\string\macro:##3->##4\noexpand\stop{%
     ##1{##3}##2{##4}%
  }}
  \next
\endgroup

\def\toksloadcsmeaning#1\to#2\and#3{%
  \begingroup
  \toks0={#2}%
  \toks2={#3}%
  \edef\next{\noexpand\toksloadmeaning@A\the\toks0 \noexpand\and\the\toks2 %
  \meaning#1\noexpand\stop
  }%
  \expandafter\endgroup\next
}
```

After `\toksloadcsmeaning\controlsequence\to{\toks1}\and{\toks3}` the token register `\toks1` contains the application template and `\toks3` the meaning of the macro.  With this in hand, writing a `\patch` macro should be a piece of cake.

Comment: What do you mean by "entry points"?

Comment: I mean macros of the package's interface that may contain a `\Return` when expanded.  It is a rather poor choice of a name, but did not have a better idea as I wrote this.