# What to do when AMS and MnSymbol packages conflict on an arrow?

Tags: symbols, packages

I need to use two arrows, one from MnSymbol and one from amssymb (`\rightsquigarrow`); unfortunately, MnSymbol redefines this command to produce its own version (which I don't want). Is there a way to redefine back the AMS arrow?

Placing the MnSymbol package to load before the AMS one does not work and the answer to this question ([how to use MnSymbol along with other packages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17370/how-to-use-mnsymbol-along-with-other-packages)) says the two packages are incompatible. I can't find the MnSymbol arrow anywhere else (`\leftpitchfork`).

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136329/best-practice-for-fixing-a-clash-between-packages-without-altering-the-sty-file

Comment: `mnsymbol` and `amssymb` don't go well together as they define so many things with same name. Best is to avoid `mnsymbol` and import only those `mnsymbols` by your self. Search this cite for examples.

Comment: Let me add it's very happy that they define same things with the same name: things sensibly can't have a different name for each font!

Comment: Also related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132453/typing-following-notation-in-latex/132456#132456

Comment: here's a "generic'
 answer: [Importing a Single Symbol From a Different Font](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14386)

Comment: Better generic answer for MnSymbol: [Importing single symbol from MnSymbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/36088/1340).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can "extract" only that symbol from `MnSymbol` and use it in your document.

This is the code to extract `\leftpitchfork`:

```
\DeclareFontFamily{U} {MnSymbolA}{}

\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolA}{m}{n}{
  <-6> MnSymbolA5
  <6-7> MnSymbolA6
  <7-8> MnSymbolA7
  <8-9> MnSymbolA8
  <9-10> MnSymbolA9
  <10-12> MnSymbolA10
  <12-> MnSymbolA12}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolA}{b}{n}{
  <-6> MnSymbolA-Bold5
  <6-7> MnSymbolA-Bold6
  <7-8> MnSymbolA-Bold7
  <8-9> MnSymbolA-Bold8
  <9-10> MnSymbolA-Bold9
  <10-12> MnSymbolA-Bold10
  <12-> MnSymbolA-Bold12}{}

\DeclareSymbolFont{MnSyA} {U} {MnSymbolA}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\leftpitchfork}{\mathrel}{MnSyA}{138}
```

And this is a MWE on how to use it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\DeclareFontFamily{U} {MnSymbolA}{}

\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolA}{m}{n}{
  <-6> MnSymbolA5
  <6-7> MnSymbolA6
  <7-8> MnSymbolA7
  <8-9> MnSymbolA8
  <9-10> MnSymbolA9
  <10-12> MnSymbolA10
  <12-> MnSymbolA12}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolA}{b}{n}{
  <-6> MnSymbolA-Bold5
  <6-7> MnSymbolA-Bold6
  <7-8> MnSymbolA-Bold7
  <8-9> MnSymbolA-Bold8
  <9-10> MnSymbolA-Bold9
  <10-12> MnSymbolA-Bold10
  <12-> MnSymbolA-Bold12}{}

\DeclareSymbolFont{MnSyA} {U} {MnSymbolA}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\leftpitchfork}{\mathrel}{MnSyA}{138}

\begin{document}
\[
A \rightsquigarrow B \qquad A \leftpitchfork B
\]
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]