# classification of basic latex commands

Tags: macros, tex-core, latex-base

Related to but not duplicating [Standard pre-defined macros in LaTeX: where to find them all](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/432655), based on how and where they are defined, what is a top-level classification of all commands, separate from those defined in document classes or packages,  available during processing of LaTeX input, and what are the most beginner-friendly resources that comprehensively catalogue the items in each of these categories?

Comment: the documented source of the latex format is available by `texdoc source2e`  so all macros defined in the latex format are defined in that file or in files like expl3 that are documented as being included in that file

Comment: The documented/commented source-code of the most recent LaTeX 2e-release (which is not necessarily the release installed on your computer!) is available as .pdf-file [source2e.pdf on CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/source2e).

Comment: TeXbook Chapter 3: Controlling TeX: TeX understands about 900 control sequences as part of its built-in vocabulary, and all of them are explained in this manual somewhere...The 900 or so control sequences that were just mentioned actually aren’t the whole story, because it’s easy to define more...you’re free to go right ahead and do it; Chapter 20 explains how...About 300 of TeX’s control sequences are called primitive; these are the low-level atomic operations that are not decomposable into simpler functions. All other control sequences are defined, ultimately, in terms of the primitive ones.